# Apply a Boolean Test to Each Value in a C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, stack, boolean, conditional-statements

I have a dictionary with chars as the keys and Stack values. I want to check that all the Stacks are empty.

```
var groupStacks = new Dictionary<char, Stack<int>>();

groupStacks.Add( '(', new Stack<int>() );//parentheses stack
groupStacks.Add( '{', new Stack<int>() );//braces stack
groupStacks.Add( '\'', new Stack<int>() );//single quotes stack
groupStacks.Add( '"', new Stack<int>() );//double quotes stack
groupStacks.Add( '[', new Stack<int>() );//brackets stack
```

I expect that, logically, I will need to iterate through the dictionary and check each Stack, but I'd prefer not to have to write a for loop for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Dictionary implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, and therefore you can use Enumerable's extension methods like .Any and .All, as those methods accept IEnumerable<> as parameters.

Therefore, I was able to do this:

```
if( groupStacks.All( s => !s.Value.Any() ) ) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: or `if( groupStacks.Values.All( v => !v.Any() ) ) { }`

Comment: Dictionary doesn't implement extension methods, it does implement `IEnumerable<T>`  and all extension methods inside of the `Enumerable`  class takes `IEnumerable<T>` (not IEnumerable) as first parameter and that's why you can call all LINQ extension methods on a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Okay, I guess technically it's not Dictionary that implements the methods, that's a good point. I'll edit and see if I can get that statement more correct.